# UI-grid 4.7.1 always getting (Error: Could not get template ui-grid/cellEditor: [object Object])

Tags: angular, user-interface, grid

I always get

```
angular.js:12722 Error: Could not get template ui-grid/cellEditor: [object Object]
    at ui-grid.core.js:11141
    at processQueue (angular.js:14991)
    at angular.js:15007
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16251)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16069)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16359)
    at done (angular.js:10791)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10989)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10930)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide some example code or explanation what you are trying to do. An error message alone is rarely helpful...

Comment: I am using angularJS 1.4.9 and ui-grid 4.7.1 and jquary 3.3.1.Inside my **index.html** added `<script src="lib/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.core.js"></script>`.Then I loaded grid i got that error message.

Comment: I resolved this matter adding my grid-option  to  `enableCellEdit: false`